# Duplicate files with find and tar

Tags: linux, find, backup, tar

I'm trying to back up a bunch of directories with tar and using find to get the files. I've seen this solution elsewhere in an old post but it duplicates every file and directory in the tarball; find itself doesn't duplicate anything

```
find d1 d2 -print0 | tar -czvf backup.tar.gz --null -T -
```

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Gnu find 4.7.0 and Gnu tar 1.29

I can just give the directories to tar, but curious why this behaviour is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `find d1 d2 -print0` including the "." directory in its output from each d1 and d2, meaning it doubles the files? Try adding --no-recursion to the tar.

Answer (score -1):

Why use find? Just pass all directories to the tar command:

```
tar -czf backup.tar.gz d1 d2
```